# How to fit the frames onto the Swiss QR invoice

Tags: java, pdf, qr-code, payment, swissqrbill

I'm implementing the software to produce the payment slip with the new QR code for our company's invoicing (according to the new [Swiss payment standard](https://www.paymentstandards.ch/en/home/schemes/payment-slips.html)) and I have troubles fitting the frames where the payer can fill in his address and the exact amount himself.

In particular on the right side, I'm running out of space. We have a creditor address and a final creditor address. So we have at least 13 lines of text plus the frame, which is rather big. The standard says hardly anything about the exact layout.

Is there any sample code available for implementing the QR invoice (preferably for Java)? Or have I missed a standard document that describes the layout of the payment part in more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the standard is rather open about the layout. But it seems to be possible to fit your information on the payment part. You can try it yourself in this [Swiss QR Bill](https://www.codecrete.net/qrbill) web site. Just delete the amount and all debtor fields and you end up with this:

[image: Swiss QR Bill]

It's indeed a very tight fit. But you might not need the reference number, the additional information and the due date. That could free up some space.

The web site seems to be related to an [open-source Java library](https://github.com/manuelbl/SwissQRBill) for the Swiss QR bill. Why not use that library?

There are further (commercial) libraries. Have a look at the (German) web page https://www.moneytoday.ch/lexikon/qr-rechnung/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the [Swiss QR bill library](https://github.com/manuelbl/SwissQRBill). That could speed up the implementation here. The resulting bill isn't pretty. But I guess the standard demands it that way.

Comment: There are quite a few pitfalls implementing the new swiss qr bill, especially layouting in the payment part requires some amount of work. If you should still having issue, we can help out as we fully implemented the specification in a Java Library (yes, it is one of the commercial libraries, but source is provided and license fee is affordable).